# Extracting and grouping elements in array in before and after values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, grouping

I'm sure it's something really basic but the solution just escapes me. 
Considering i have an array like

```
'2015-06-12 07:00:56', 'aa',
 '2015-02-17 15:12:31', 'bb',
 '2016-02-08 11:45:12', 'cc',
'2016-02-07 11:45:12', 'dd'
```

I can instantly group the elements in my head in this manner

before:bb
after:aa

before:aa 
after:dd

before:dd
after:cc

Not sure how would I extract and group the elements like this in code. Got as far as ordering the array 
https://jsfiddle.net/6wt6gqbw/

```
var a = [['2015-06-12 07:00:56', 'aa'], ['2015-02-17 15:12:31', 'bb'], ['2016-02-08 11:45:12', 'cc'],['2016-02-07 11:45:12', 'dd']];

a.sort();

before = '';
beforeArr = [];
afterArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {


    {
     before +=  a[i][1] + ',';
    }

beforeF = before.substr(0, before.length - 1);

}

console.log(beforeF);
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: BTW: Why `a.sort();`? `sort` doesn't properly work with 2D arrays (by default).

Comment: Thinking could return them in values = {
before: ["bb","aa","dd"],
after: ["aa","dd","cc"]
} for the sort will need to sort by the date to be able to get the before and after values. Every 2 elements are grouped in pairs of two even if the array is 1 element short will mean the after value will be null .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a simple sorting by date. You can sort date strings as plain strings, if they are [ISO 6801](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates.

Later you can get parts of the array with the sorted tems.

```js
var a = [['2015-06-12 07:00:56', 'aa'], ['2015-02-17 15:12:31', 'bb'], ['2016-02-08 11:45:12', 'cc'], ['2016-02-07 11:45:12', 'dd']];

a.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
});

var content = a.map(function (a) { return a[1]; }),
    before = content.slice(0, content.length - 1),
    after = content.slice(1);
document.write("<pre>a " + JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>content " + JSON.stringify(content, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>before " + JSON.stringify(before, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>after " + JSON.stringify(after, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```